# Laravel 7 Upload with XMLHttpRequest response is always null even if the network inspector does get it

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, xmlhttprequest

In a previous Laravel 7 project I used `XMLHttpRequest()` to upload a file with progress bar successfully. Now, in a forked project where I need this similar code, the `XMLHttpRequest` always returns the response as null. What is going wrong?

Here is the upload.js part:

```
function upload(params...){
   var data = new FormData();
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.responseType = "json";

   request.onload = function() {
     console.log(`Loaded: ${request.status} ${request.response}`);//request.response IS ALWAYS NULL but the status is 200, statusText = 'OK' and readyState = 4.
   };

   request.open("post",url);
   request.send(data);
}
```

Here is the corresponding **uploadController.php** who sends back the response:

```
if($fileUploaded){
  return response()->json(
    [
       'message'=>'File uploaded successfully ',
       'filename'=>$fileUploaded,
    ]
  );
}
```

**Notes**:

- The file is uploaded correctly and registered in the database.
- If I change `request.responseType = "json";` to whatever else, the response is no longer null, but I get it in XML format!

Why do I get `request.response` as null?

This is the response:

```
XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: "http://myApp.local/upload", status: 200, statusText: "OK", responseType: "json", response: null }
```

If I inspect the network, `the uploadController.php` does get the json response. However, from the javascript side, it's null. Why? Can anyone shed some light?

**Solved**
Guys, thank you. My bad... I'd forgotten some var_dump()s left behind in my code, which were causing the `request.response` to be `null`.

Comment: how about you remove the thumbs up special character? also the 2nd argument to response()->json is redundant and can be removed too

Comment: Check the `Accept` header being sent from JavaScript to the backend and the `Content-Type` header in the response. They should be `application/json`

Comment: Guys, thank you. My bad... I had forgotten some `var_dump()`s left behind in my code, that was causing the `request.response` to be `null` :P

Answer (score 0):

Man, have you already checked whether your backend is printing information?

Maybe you've forgotten to comment a `dd()` or `var_dump()` function.

Use the "inspect element" tool of your favorite browser. Right at the "network" tab, check the response. There might be some extra text coming right from a `var_dump` or something like that.